# Dúvida sobre plataforma hibrida

Tags: app

Quero ampliar os meus conhecimentos, com isso estou começando a olhar o front-end,
 vi um pouco de html 5, css3, js.
Minha intenção é desenvolver sistemas híbridos web,android e ios.
A dúvida seria como desenvolver uma única vez e usar nessas três plataformas, para isso o que poderia usar?
react/react native, angular, flutter ou vou precisar fazer separadamente para cada plataforma?
Ví alguns videos sobre essas três ferramentas mas não me esclareceu essa dúvida,

Comment: então realmente não usa nenhuma linguagem de back-end java, python swift, kotlin

Answer (score 1):

A idéia do desenvolvimento híbrido é você poder construir o seu aplicativo programando apenas uma vez sem a necessidade de desenvolver para cada plataforma (Android ou IOS). Como você mesmo citou, existem várias opções. como Cordova/Phonegap, Ionic ou React Native.

Para o desenvolviemento híbrido, um bom conhecimento em javascript é necessário.

Se você usar Cordova/Phonegap, vai poder desenvolver em HTML, CSS + Javascript.

Se você utilizar o IONIC, também vai usar HTML, mas a programação é em Angular/Typescript

Por fim, se a sua escolha for React Native, você não vai usar o HTML e o CSS, o layout é feito de forma diferente. A programação é em Javascript.

Uma diferença entre React Native e os outros dois é que no caso do React Native o layout é nativo, ou seja, ao compilar a aplicação é criando um layout nativo da plataforma, acoplado a sua programação em javascript. Nos outros dois, ao compilar é criando uma webview e o seu aplicativo roda dentro dele. O React acaba exigindo mais esforço, mas tem um desempenho melhor.

Apesar do código ser único, pode ser necessário ajustes específicos para Android ou IOS.

Aqui tem alguns links para te ajudar a entender melhor estas plataformas:

https://rocketseat.com.br/starter

https://loiane.training/curso/phonegap-apache-cordova

https://tekzoom.com.br/ionic-framework-documentacao-e-aplicacoes-completas-para-download-gratis-video-02/